# Unable to use search() with a variable pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/mrQEz/1/ - where I'm having trouble using the JavaScript search() function with a variable pattern.

The code searches div.answer for the word you enter into the filter field. I want the search to be case insensitive so I want to get the "i" flag at the end of the search pattern.  If I directly enter /background/i as the search pattern, in line 9 of the JavaScript, I find "Background" fine in the text. But if I enter "background" in the filter field and try to build the search pattern from

```
term = "/" + this.value + "/i";
```

it doesn't work, even though term seems to have the right thing in it: /background/i.

Does anyone see the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways of creating [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) in JavaScript. The first is the literal syntax:

```
term = /background/i;
```

But if you would like to convert a string to a regular expression, you need to call the `RegExp` constructor:

```
term = new RegExp(this.value, "i");
```

You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/P5cCq/).